# SQL Find difference between previous and current row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the difference between the current row and the previous row. However, I am getting the following error message:

> The multi-part identifier "tableName" could not be bound.

Not sure how to fix the error.

Thanks!

Output should look like the following:

```
columnOfNumbers     Difference
      1               NULL
      2               1
      3               1
      10              7
      12              2
      ....            ....
```

Code:

```
USE DATABASE;

WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tableName ORDER BY columnOfNumbers) ROW,
    columnOfNumbers
    FROM tableName)
SELECT
    a.columnOfNumbers
FROM
    CTE a
    LEFT JOIN CTE b
    ON a.columnOfNumbers = b.columnOfNumbers AND a.ROW = b.ROW + 1
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You have to partition by a column name.

Comment: can just omit the 'partition by' clause.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad6e5/1)

```
;WITH tblDifference AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber, columnOfNumbers 
    FROM tableName
)

SELECT cur.columnOfNumbers, cur.columnOfNumbers - previous.columnOfNumbers
FROM tblDifference cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDifference previous
ON cur.RowNumber = previous.RowNumber + 1
```

Answer (score 48):

If you in SQL Server 2012+ You can use LAG.

```
 SELECT columnOfNumbers
       ,columnOfNumbers - LAG(columnOfNumbers, 1) OVER (ORDER BY columnOfNumbers)
   FROM tableName
```

Note: The optional third parameter of LAG is:

> default
>
> The value to return when scalar_expression at offset is NULL.
> If a default value is not specified, NULL is returned. default can be
> a column, subquery, or other expression, but it cannot be an analytic
> function. default must be type-compatible with scalar_expression.

Comment: Nice solution, but it give the wrong result for the first row, 1 instead of null.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't read the desired sample output carefully enough. If  we omit the 3rd paramteer in LAG that is default 0 it will instead give a null int he first row.

Comment: I compared this to the other posted solution with ROW_NUMBER, but to have the same data available, I added another LAG to also get primary key of previous record, to then do a join. This method took less than half the time compared to using ROW_NUMBER join.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the `partition by` statement:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnOfNumbers) as ROW,
             columnOfNumbers
      FROM tableName
     )
SELECT a.columnOfNumbers, a.columnOfNumbers - b.columnOfNumbers
FROM CTE a LEFT JOIN
     CTE b
     ON a.ROW = b.ROW + 1;
```

If you do need it, you should put in a column name as opposed to a table name.

Comment: I tried this query, but it returns NULLS in the second column. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3356901 . . . It returned `NULL`s because I left in your condition `a.columnOfNumbers = b.columnOfNumbers`.